# Loopback 4: non-primitive properties instead of relations

Tags: loopbackjs

Using Loopback 4, I want to use the type-safety of Typescript in my application code while getting the schema validation from the repository decorators, but store a property as serialized json (in this case, Postgres bson) instead of as a separate entity with a FK relation.

Consider a address book `Contact` model that could have a list of phone numbers:

```
@model()
export class PhoneNumber {

  @property({ required: true })
  number: string;

  @property()
  type: string; 

}

@model()
export class Contact extends Entity {

  @property({ id: true, required: true })
  id: string;

  @property({ required: true })
  email: string;

  @property({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @property.array(PhoneNumber)
  phoneNumbers: PhoneNumber[];

  constructor(data?: Partial<Contact>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

In the above example, I get full schema validation, but if I try to save an instance of `Contact` using a generated `Repository` that extends `DefaultCrudRespository`, it just drops whatever was provided in the `phoneNumbers` field and saves an empty column in the db.

If I change the property annotation to:

```
  @property.array(Object)
  phoneNumbers: PhoneNumber[];
```

It will save the field properly, serialized as json, but it won't attempt to validate the field, and also won't specify the type as an array `PhoneNumber` in the generated openapi.json spec

It seems that Loopback 3 had support for embedded models: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Embedded-models-and-relations.html

No mention of it in the Loopback 4 docs, though.

Comment: I think the issue you are experiencing is partially caused by the problem described here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2130 However, I suspect there is more than that, I think we need to fix the way how LB4 converts array properties to from LB4 definitions to LB3/juggler definitions. Could you please open a new issue on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Try use the strict mode filter in the model PhoneNumber

```
@model({settings: {strict: "filter"}})
```

This make any unknow field be ignored when add in the database